# Añadir valores a array

Tags: php, array

Estoy intentando añadir a un array números aleatorios con array_push en el campo 'notas' => [ ] pero creo que no lo estoy haciendo bien ya que no veo los números aleatorios guardados en el array.

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma :

```
$persona1= [
    'nombre' => 'persona1',
    'notas' => []
];

$persona2= [
    'nombre' => 'persona2',
    'notas' => []
];

$persona3= [
    'nombre' => 'persona3',
    'notas' => []
];

$datos=[$persona1, $persona2, $persona3];
$_SESSION['datos'] = $datos;


function insertarNumAleatorios(){

   $datos = $_SESSION['datos'];

   foreach ( $datos as $alumno ) {

      array_push($alumno['notas'] = random(0,10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Usas mal el parámetro que le pasas a `array_push`. Además, la función para generar números aleatorios en PHP es `rand()` y no `random()`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La forma correcta de lograr lo que te propones es la siguiente:

```
array_push($alumno['notas'], rand(0, 10));
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Saludos